# how to Tokenize payfort merhant page 2 while integrating with rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, payfort

I'm Integrating my rails application with payfort using payfort api merchant page 2.0 I've made a form that collects user data and in my back end I do calculate the signature so the result is like this

`

```
parametsrs ={
           :access_code=>"4XiE5d2D9Yvbbb9YMYPE",
           :card_number=>4005550000000001,
           :card_security_code=>123, 
           :expiry_date=>1705,
           :language=>"en",
           :merchant_identifier=>"MpFMkQYk",
           :merchant_reference=>139,
           :service_command=>" TOKENIZATION"
           :signature => "d0f49bf93d76939dd9f841302f4d6ca87151a54ceffca725b38cdaf9a1a2fdb0"}
```

`

but whenever I submit this form I got this response `invalid extra parameters` 
can anyone help me with that?

Comment: did you find a solution ?!

Comment: there is space before TOKENIZATION

Comment: I believe, you should contact Payfort Back Office team and ask them to activate Merchant Page 2.0 instead of simple Merchant Page. I had the same issue and solved it that way.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove rails extra parameters like  ***utf8 , authenticity_token , _method*** before submitting to payfort

Comment: I am facing a different issue. Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42432826/payfort-in-ruby-on-rails-application)