# Payfort in Ruby On Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payfort

I wish to implement the payfort gateway with my rails application.But I am very much novice to api. I am having a look at the [this docs](https://docs.payfort.com/docs/merchant-page-two/build/index.html#merchant-page-2-0-request). But i am not clear with where to start? Is there any gem for it?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no Gems for sorry , but api is rest so you can implement what you want easily.
But the best thing is to start with creating your own Gateway with [Active Merchant.](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/wiki/contributing)

Comment: Please have a look at my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436425/integrating-payfort-payment-with-ruby-on-rails-app) for same.

Answer (score 0):

```
1-Sort all PayFort requests parameters in an ascending alphabetical order based on the parameters names as follow: 

params={access_code=stbbRGM7K1rHXliCQeNwtk,
amount=250,
command=PURCHASE,
currency=QAR,
customer_email=test@gmail.com,
customer_ip=103.43.154.34,
language=en,
merchant_identifier=YRssfesdsd,
merchant_reference=REFRRSERRFFE4444,
token_name=6RTD55DVVVBDSCCVVCFCCV}
params = params.sort.to_h
string = params.to_query(nil)
string = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest string
  params.store 'signature',string 
  uri = URI.parse("https://sbpaymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi")
  header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header)
```